# Calculation of element widths when floated in Opera 11.*

Tags: css, layout, opera, css-float

I'm dealing with an issue in the Opera 11.5 beta (I am presuming this is relevant to all Opera 11 releases) whereby a floated, block-level element (an un-ordered list) is being given an arbitrary fixed width and causing the child elements to wrap - in the same way to IE6 does.

The element is floated right and currently has no siblings. There are no widths specified for lists in my stylesheet.

I was wondering what sort of logic Opera uses to calculate width in these instances?

I have uploaded an image comparing Opera 11.5 to Firefox 4.1 with Dragonfly/Firebug output.

http://twitpic.com/55f79o/full

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/i_like_robots/HKAQ9/

Comment: Please provide a [jsFiddle test case](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: Jsfilddle or live example would help a lot.

Comment: One jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/i_like_robots/HKAQ9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why yet (will look later)

but Opera is not liking the `replace` class not having a width on it

```
.replace {
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    background: no-repeat 0 0;
    width: 10px;
}
```

I presume that class(by it's name) is to house a replacement background image, so it should be OK to put a width on it?

**Updated** it is connected to the `text-indent` method of text hiding - without the text indent it is also fine in Opera

Comment: Nice investigation work! I'll work on this to find out if it is a definite bug or quirk we can ignore.

Answer (score 2):

According to me it is a bug in Opera.

When calculating the width of an element it calculates based on the sum total of all the width of child elements but if you have 2 Div elements as child displaying as block elements actually the width is not sum total of both the elements.

To fix the issue all you have to do is specify the width of the parent element instead of allowing Opera to calculate.

@clairesuzy -  You can see the bug in action with the code I have posted here http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=27000